# Is it possible to make this loop simpler?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string-formatting

The duplication of `p1`, `p2`, `p3` bugs me.

```
y.zip(r, q).each { |p1, p2, p3|
  puts '%5s %5s | %3s' % [p1, p2, p3]
}
```

Maybe there is a solution with `map`? Is there a way to insert the variables directly into the string rather than using this formatting?

Comment: what is the value of y?

Comment: y, r and q are all arrays with equal length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each element of the `zip`'d array is an array, you can just use the whole array

```
y.zip(r, q).each {|p| puts '%5s %5s | %3s' % p}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y.zip(r, q).each {|*p| puts '%5s %5s | %3s' % p}
```

Comment: That's not going to work, `p` will be an array containing a nested array and the nested array will have three elements but the outer array won't. You'll get a "too few arguments" for the puts.

Comment: What is your '*p' supposed to do?
It gives me an ArgumentError for using too few arguments.

Comment: `*p` is a way of packing (or unpacking) arguments into (out of) an array. It can be a useful technique.... for example if you have a method `foo` and you don't know how many arguments will be passed, you can automatically combine them into an array.  You would do `foo('Sam', 'Joe', 'Pete')` but when you define the method you woul do `def foo(*names)` giving you an array called `names` instead of `def foo(name_1 name_2, name_3)` giving you three separate variables.